# Apply around advice to existing EJB

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, weblogic, interceptor

We have a third party application deployed on JBoss and Weblogic. We need to log access to EJBs in this application for audit purposes. Is it possible to apply a transparent service that will log all calls to these EJBs to a file or database ?

The only option that I can think of is to use Spring as a business delegate and modify clients to use the Spring bean. Unfortunately, we do not have an option of modifying client code and this has to be done on the server in a way that our code gets executed before and after EJBs are invoked by clients.

I searched for a solution for this and have found nothing that could point me the right direction.

Thank you for the help.

**Edit:**

After further research, it appears that JBoss does support custom EJB interceptors. Configuration for this is possible using standardjboss.xml for EJB 2.x and ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml for EJB 3.x

As it turns out, there is not much available by way of samples on how to create such interceptors for use with EJB 2.x - which is what I need. It does not appear too difficult and I will try this to see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just use straight forward EJB 3 interceptors. Look for DefaultInterceptor in http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/EJB3_Interceptors.html to see how to apply an interceptor to all ejbs in your deployment. This is supported by the EJB 3 spec.

For EJB 2.x in JBoss, take a look at standard-jboss.xml. There you can either modify the full default containers for the different ejb types. You can also create a new container configuration in standard-jboss.xml and add your interceptors there and associate your EJBs with the new configuration by including a jboss.xml in your ejb.jar META-INF/ folder. Or, if I remember correctly, you can both define the new container configuration and the association in META-INF/jboss.xml. Some information here: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/EJBDeployer_MBean-Container_configuration_information.html